# Call Matlab function from Python script: "not enough values to unpack" ValueError

Tags: python, matlab

I called a Matlab function from Python, the function has 3 outputs. Python gives `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`. Here's the Matlab function `testCalledByPython`:

```
function [otpt1, otpt2, otpt3] = testCalledByPython(inpt)
otpt1 = rand(inpt, inpt);
otpt2 = magic(inpt);
otpt3 = zeros(inpt, inpt);
```

This is the Python script to call the above function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
otpt1, otpt2, otpt3 = eng.testCalledByPython(2)
```

If I replace the last line by `otpt1, otpt2 = eng.testCalledByPython(2)`, it runs, but the outputs are:

```
otpt1, otpt2
Out[5]: 
(matlab.double([0.8147236863931789,0.12698681629350606]),
 matlab.double([0.9057919370756192,0.9133758561390194]))
```

Obviously these are wrong outputs. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution myself. It's actually explained in Matlab Documentation:
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html

So knowing there are 3 outputs, the way to do it is changing last line of Python script to:

`otpt1, otpt2, otpt3 = eng.testCalledByPython(2, nargout = 3)`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar problem, however I was using the runtime method without API engine.

So knowing that I required/expected x outputs from the function, I added the argument of `nargout = x` inside the function that I wanted to use or get output from.